# Why is Ternary Operator Considered an Expression and not a Statement?

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I know that an expression produces a value while a statement is an action. However, I don't understand why the ternary operator falls under the category of an expression.

From what I understand, the ternary operator is simply a shorthand version of an "if/else" statement. But that's a statement. So why is it that the ternary operator not a statement like its longer counterpart?

Comment: Because you can assign it's result to a variable. Fun fact: in kotlin if else is an expression and you can assign it's result to a variable

Comment: Expressions are evaluated to produce a value. Statements are executed to perform an action.

Comment: It is not really short hand for if/else since if else is not returning a value.

Comment: It's called the conditional operator. It's merely *a* ternary operator.

Comment: Can you not also return a value by doing something like "if(a) {return 1} else {return 2}"? Is it not the same as "a ? 1 : 2"? Is the ternary operator not also performing an action too since it's basically the same in this scenario?

Comment: "return a value" here means "evaluate to a value" aka "results in a value" as opposed to "cause the function to return with a value." I've updated my answer to be clearer.

Comment: `if(a) {return 1} else {return 2}` is not the same as `a ? 1 : 2`. The former cause the function to return. The latter doesn't. (In fact, the latter effectively does nothing at all if used somewhere the former could be used.)

Comment: `if(a) {return 1} else {return 2}` causes a *function call* to result in a value, but the if itself didn't result in a value.

Answer (score 2):

It's not 'simply a shorthand version of an "if/else"'. It's intended to be used when you want a conditional value, e.g.

```
variable = condition ? value1 : value2;
```

instead of writing

```
if (condition) {
    variable = value1;
} else {
    variable = value2;
}
```

Any expression can be used as a statement, so it's *possible* to use a ternary as a shorthand `if/else`, e.g.

```
condition ? console.log("True") : alert("False");
```

You'll often find this in minified or obfuscated code, but many programmers consider it poor style in regular code.

Not all `if/else` can be shortened like this, because the body of `if` can contain statements, but you can only use expressions in the sub-expressions of a ternary.

Answer (score 2):

An expression is a piece of code that results in (evaluates to) a value.

- `4 + 4` is an expression.
- `a[ i ]` is an expression.

We don't always care about the value to in which it results. Still an expression, though.

- `x = y` is an expression.
- `console.log( "Hi" )` is an expression.

The conditional operator results in a value.

```js
cond ? 123 : 456   // Results in either `123` or `456`.
```

If it didn't, it wouldn't make sense to place it on the right-hand side of an `=`, like here:

```js
val = cond ? 123 : 456;   // `val` is now `123` or `456`.
```

An if statement doesn't result in a value. It can't be used as an expression.

```js
val = if ...    // WRONG!
```